# login issues with Flex-Salesforce

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, salesforce

I am using Flex-Force API to connect to Salesforce. I have hard coded my Salesforce login details in the code and using them to connect to Salesforce.
When I use my SWF directly it works fine but when I place it inside a VisualForce Page and try to access it the login functionality fails.

Has any one from you faced a similar issue while working in Flex-Salesforce or has some idea on this ?
Please suggest ..................

Thanks and Regards.
Ashine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a VisualForce page you should login with the SessionID not the credentials.  To do this you need to setup the html object embed tag to pass the sessionID to the SWF and then call the loginBySessionId method to do the login.  A complete walk through of how to do this is on my blog:
http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/26/building-client-cloud-apps-with-flash-builder-for-force-com/

Comment: I will try and let you know the results !!

Comment: I am using the same approach at flex side and using ' app.loginBySessionId(sid)' to connect to salesforce. However, at Salesforce side I am using apex (and not S-Controls) as follows, can this be a source of error ?
<apex:page>
          <apex:flash src="{!$Resource.MYSWF}" width="900" height="640" flashvars="sessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190}"/>
</apex:page>

Comment: It gives the following error message: 
INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session

Any idea ...................... :(

Comment: Can you verify the value that is being sent to Flex?  Make sure it looks correct.

Comment: Today I commented out everything and used only 

'app.serverUrl = parameters["serverUrl"]; 
app.loginByCredentials(username, password);


This allowed me to access this SWF in a VF page but when I try running this via site page it agains fail to login.
Any idea why this SWF is not working in site 'http://mysite.dev2.cs3.force.com/myproject/sitepage' but works in VF 'https://cs3.salesforce.comapexmypage'.                                                                               Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have hard coded my own user name and password in my flex application and use it to connect to Salesforce. Can it be the case that my login is limited to VF only and not for site page, just a thought !!

Comment: I could be the cross-domain request that is failing.  You should enable logging for to get an error message.  Or use the AsyncResponder fault event.